# On the subject of anagrams

Tags: wordplay, anagram

How many words or phrases shown below (Blockquotes) are anagrams of the phrases or the words listed here in this entire puzzle-including the answer?

> A dry plow
>
> Sword
>
> Where is the Lord’s, Ted?
>
> No
>
> Silted
>
> Eve sins
>
> An umber
>
> Is thin
>
> Rose shape

The answer is ______    (Fill in the blank with a number spelled out )

Explain your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is:

> indeterminate

Because:

> A dry plow = **wordplay** (a tag) **(1)**
>  Sword = **words**  **(2)**
>  Where is the Lord’s, Ted? = **the words listed here**  **(3)**
>  No = **on** (in the title)  **(4)**
>  Silted = **listed**  **(5)**
>  Eve sins = is seven (but only if the answer is seven)
>  An umber = **a number**  **(6)**
>  Is thin = **in this**  **(7)**
>  Rose shape - contains "phrases", but that leaves "oe".

> So I have seven anagrams excluding "Eve sins" but:
>  If I put "The answer is **seven**", I have an eighth.
>  And if I put "The answer is **eight**", I only have seven.
>  Hmm...
>
>  So I guess I'll have to say:
>  The answer is **one more than six**

Comment: vs lbh vapyhqr vf frira gura gurer ner rvtug nafjref vapyhqvat n qel cybhtu. Vs lbh qb abg gurer ner 7

Comment: Ah, a little word in blue. I have a blind spot for tags.

Comment: Now you see the dilemma?